# .Net Socket blocking when sending to a Java socket

Tags: c#, java, .net, sockets

I have a simple Java Server Socket but when I connect to it with a C#.Net Socket and Send to the Java Socket it blocks and I have to shutdown the .Net socket send for it to stop blocking. This them means I have to close the socket after each communication. Where am i going wrong?

```
socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress.Text), 8089);
                socket.Connect(ip);
 byte[] b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            socket.Send(b, b.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
        int timeout = 0;
        while (socket.Available == 0)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            timeout++;
        }


        string response = "";
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int total = 0;
        while (socket.Available > 0)
        {
            int len = socket.Receive(buffer);
            total += len;
            response = response + (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, len));
            buffer = new byte[1024];
            if (socket.Available == 0) Thread.Sleep(250);
        }
        MessageBox.Show(response);
        return response.Trim();

    }
```

ServerSide

```
clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        clientSocket.setKeepAlive(true);
        Log.d("DbThread","client Connected");

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()),8192);
        bo = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()),8192);

        Thread.sleep(100);
        char[] buffer = new char[8192];

        int len=0;
        String build = "";
        while((len = br.read(buffer))>0){

            build = build + new String(buffer);
            buffer = new char[8192];
        }

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(build.trim());
        Log.d("input",build.trim());
        String output = "";
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        switch(json.getString("classType").charAt(0))
        {
        case 'Q':
            Log.d("classType","Q");
            Query query = gson.fromJson(build.trim(), Query.class);
            output = query.executeToJson();Log.d("Query","end");break;

        case 'I':
            Log.d("classType","I");
            Insert insert = gson.fromJson(build.trim(), Insert.class);
            output = insert.executeToJson();break;

        case 'U':
            Log.d("classType","U");
            Update update = gson.fromJson(build.trim(), Update.class);
            output = update.executeToJson();break;

        case 'D':
            Log.d("classType","D");
            Delete delete = gson.fromJson(build.trim(), Delete.class);
            output = delete.executeToJson();break;

        }       



        bo.write(output);
        bo.flush();

        Log.d("Query",output);

    br.close();
```

Comment: Remember that sockets are, by default, _blocking_. This means that things like accepting new connections, or receiving data, will block if there is nothing waiting.

Comment: You have to show the other side too.

Comment: where in this does it stop? the top loop? or the bottom loop? or...?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, checking `Available` as the loop exit condition is unsafe; all that tells you is what is buffered locally; that has nothing to do with the end of the stream.

Secondly, adding a `Thread.Sleep` is not an ideal way to do this; just Read or Recieve; that will block until *some* data is available; typically you just a loop over a Read or Receive.

One obvious condition where it will hang: if the other machine hasn't sent any reply; in which case it will sit forever in the topmost loop.

Additional notes:

- you *should not* need to allocate a new `buffer` each iteration; the previous 8192 buffer is still fine; re-use it
- you *should not* assume that your buffer has entire characters in it, especially since you are using UTF8; your buffer could have part of a multi-byte representation of a character; it is usually easier to make sure you have an entire message / frame before starting to decode

Personally I would investigate this by adding lots of debug output, and a network sniffer.

Comment: It blocks at the socket.send. I as though the Java Socket doesn't know the transmission has ended. hence why I have to shutdown the send transmission.

Comment: @user1240059 if you don't close the socket, then the transmission *hasn't* ended. Hence hy you often use "framing" on a socket. I'm confused though: you say it blocks on the send, then talk about the shutdown - but the shutdown is *after* the send - so: does it get to the shutdown? Where **exactly** does it block?

Comment: I think it's the java server socket is blocking at the read. I think it doesn't recognise the end of transmission unless I force the .net client socket to close the sending stream.

Comment: @user1240059 right; then you need to find out what the "framing" protocol is on this API. That is unique to your API, so I cannot tell you what this is. It could be as simple as "add a CRLF", or "add a zero-byte". It could be much more complicated. Without a "framing" protocol, it is correct to say that the message is not complete until the socket is closed.

Comment: I have tried everything at the end I can think of. I am sending from a System.Net.Sockets.Socket to a Java.Net.ServerSocket. I know it is the Java server socket blocking on the read it receives all the data I send but is expecting more. There must be something I can send to stop the server socket blocking without having to run socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send). Please help!!

Comment: @user1240059 no, unless you have a framing definition, that is entirely correct; a stream does not end until it closes. If you could show me what the java read-loop was doing, we might get somewhere (i.e. identify the framing from the source), but: without some kind of framing, the **only** way to say "end of message" is: to close the stream. I expect that Java does have a framing definition, but you're just not using it.

Comment: it is above. 'while((len = br.read(buffer))>0){ 
 
            build = build + new String(buffer); 
            buffer = new char[8192]; 
        } 
'

Comment: When you do a BufferedWriter.close() or flush(); it must send something to the reader so it knows it it the end of transmission. Failing this I will have to get the client to send the number of bytes in a header.

Comment: @user1240059 Flush **does nothing**. Nothing at all. If you call Close, it closes the socket; *that* is detectable, indeed. Closing the socket (or at least one direction) is the **only** thing that means "end of transmission", unless you add it yourself. The client sending the number of bytes would be: framing. So: exactly what I've been saying. That reader code just reads to the end of the stream, so only responds to stream closure.

Comment: Ok, I see the problem now. .Net is just sending bytes over the network. Where as Java opens a Stream. Therefore is it possble to open the .NET Socket with an input and output stream . Or use a Java socket the just reads bytes and I do my own framing.

Comment: @user1240059 that is a false distinction. There is no technical difference between a Stream and a series of chunks of bytes. You can use NetworkStream if you want to achieve the same, but it will change nothing.

Comment: I have used network stream and when I send to the server the server does not block. This means I can send and receive messages from the server without close the stream or socket. The network stream must use the same frame method a the Java stream. I suspect the first few bytes must have the length.

Comment: @user1240059 NetworkStream is **just** a convenience wrapper around the socket API. It does not change the data; it does not add any length prefix (unless you do that yourself), nor change the nature of TCP.

Comment: @user1240059 it is a good question, but there's absolutely no fundamental difference between them. Did you close/dispose the stream? Or use `using` etc? Another consideration may be the options used when creating the stream - in particular, whether nagle is enabled/disabled.